# QPaintEvent painting region in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

This is a basic doubt regarding the `Painting` done in Qt.
I have a `QScrollArea` as my `centralWidget` in `Main Window` of my Application. I have added a `QFrame` `frame` to the `scrollarea`. The `Layout` of the `QFrame` is `QGridLayout`.
When I add `widgets` to the `layout` like this:

```
MainWindow::AddLabel()
{
    setUpdatesEnabled(false);
    QGridLayout *myGrid = (QGridLayout *)ui->frame->layout();
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        QLabel *label = new QLabel();
        QString str;
        str.SetNum(i);
        label->SetText(str);
        myGrid->AddWidget(label, 0, i, 0);//add label to i'th column of row 0
    }
    setUpdatesEnabled(true);
    repaint();
}
```

***Please dont worry about the memory leak as it is not the focus of the question.***
So my doubt's are:

1. Is setting the updates `disabled` during adding widgets to layout any helpful?
2. Even if I maximise the window not all the QLabel's will be visible to me. So when the code flow leaves the above function & goes to the event loop then are all the QLabel's & the enormous area of QFrame painted? Or only those QLabel's which are visible & only that much area of QFrame which is visible painted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a form (.ui) then the widgets inside the `ui` ***are not children*** of your widget `MainWindow`. Well , `setUpdatesEnabled()` only affect the current widget as well as its children, so the object `ui->frame` will still receive updates after `myGrid->AddWidget`. Change to

```
  ui->frame->setUpdatesEnabled(false);
  ...
  ui->frame->setUpdatesEnabled(true);
```

Btw, when you enable updates, then screen will be updated. So you dont need to call `repaint();` on any widget.

Comment: Thank You that cleared lots of doubts of mine!
I will make the required changes :)